# Intellij Idea - Could not autowire. No beans of 'ApplicationRepository' type found. less... (Ctrl+F1) Checks autowiring problems in a bean class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

I am Java newbie.

I am making this [tutorial](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+Spring+MVC%2C+Hibernate+and+JSON) (Spring MVC + Hibernate + Tomcat)

Everything goes fine till now. When I tried to make a `ApplicationController` I could not autowire `ApplicationRepository`.

I get this error message and `404` error code when I deploy application:

```
Could not autowire. No beans of 'ApplicationRepository' type found. less...     
(Ctrl+F1) 
Checks autowiring problems in a bean class.
```

Ok talk is cheap.

Here goes the **repo** (github!): https://github.com/maciejkowalski/sample-spring-app

Tomcat **stacktrace**: https://gist.github.com/maciejkowalski/c7512d82feb75fcebd5f

Here is the **code**:

**root/src/main/java/wzpweb/**

```
package wzpweb;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "applications")
public class Application {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    private String name;

    @Basic
    private String ip;

    @Basic
    private Boolean alive;

    @Basic
    private Integer port;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public Boolean getAlive() {
        return alive;
    }

    public void setAlive(Boolean alive) {
        this.alive = alive;
    }

    public Integer getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(Integer port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

}
```

---

```
package wzpweb;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class ApplicationController {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationRepository applicationRepository;
    // THIS IS NOT WORKING !! ACHTUNG!

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listApplications(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("application", new Application());
        model.addAttribute("applications", applicationRepository.findAll());
        return "users";
    }

}
```

---

```
package wzpweb;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ApplicationRepository extends JpaRepository<Application, Long> {
}
```

**root/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="wzpweb"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="wzpweb"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="defaultPersistenceUnit"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

---

**root/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

---

**root/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistance.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sample"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="123" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**root/pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>WZP_aplikacja_web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WZP_aplikacja_web</name>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>WZP_aplikacja_web</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

**EDIT #1**

I have edited `web.xml` and added code:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

But now I get  `Element listener-class is not allowed her` from Intellij IDEA.

And my app even doesnt deploy.

---

**EDIT #2**

Well problem still occurs.

I renamed `persistance.xml` to `persistence.xml`.

Restarted Intellij idea and still getting this error.

Maybe this is a bug?

I will probably surrender with this Spring stuff, it's beyond me...

Comment: Thats the third code here. Or you can check github: https://github.com/maciejkowalski/sample-spring-app/blob/master/src/main/java/wzpweb/ApplicationRepository.java

Comment: Take a look at my answer. The error is really weak lol.

Comment: There is a fixed version of this tutorial for those, who has problem to find together all the fixes: https://bitbucket.org/cg-lab/intellij-getting-started-with-spring-mvc-hibernate-and-json

Comment: thanks for the answers. To be honest, I switched from Spring to RoR that day (Apr 23, 2013), I have 3+ years as Ruby dev. I wrote this quick project in one day...

Answer (score 14):

I followed the same tutorial and ran into the same code inspection warning (even if the application was working fine, the IDE was complaining). To make fix it, I added `@Repository` to my JpaRepository:

For your example:

```
package wzpweb;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

@Repository
public interface ApplicationRepository extends JpaRepository<Application, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rename your file `persistance.xml` to `persistence.xml`. The `persistence.xml` is, by default, the name of the file needed in the `META-INF/` directory to define a persistence unit needed by your entityManagerFactory.

[Here](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/)'s a blog post explaining how Spring uses your custom interface implementing `JpaRepository` to generate an implementation class. I originally thought that you needed an implementation class for it, but that is **not** the case.

Small bug in the naming is your problem, given away by your first exception in the stack trace.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named defaultPersistenceUnit
```

Comment: Soo looks like this tutorial is outdated. http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+Spring+MVC%2C+Hibernate+and+JSON

Comment: I will check this answer in 1 minute. :) Thanks.

Comment: Is this a good source to implement that class? https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java (copy-paste and check some code :) )

Comment: @nothing-special-here Ignore everything I've said before and do what I put in my answer. I was on the wrong track because I hadn't looked at the full stacktrace.

Comment: Another exception :) -> https://gist.github.com/maciejkowalski/6fca0363f8a37c5987b7

Comment: @nothing-special-here Can you push your changes to git? That is the same exception as before. Did you make sure to name it correctly? `persistence.xml`

Comment: OK, I added a quick commit for that.

Comment: @nothing-special-here It seems right to me. Try recompiling your whole project. And go over anything you hand-wrote for typos.

Answer (score 1):

Add a context loader listener to your web.xml to read the Spring app context XML on startup.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml,/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext-*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Can you explain more in details, please? I am a total newbie. :)

Comment: Oops, I don't have `applicationContext.xml` file.

Comment: It still doesn't works. I will edit my post and add more info.

Comment: @nothing-special-here The `<listener>` element must come before all `<servlet>` elements. Still, this won't help.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis OK, I fixed this and error doesn't appear but I still can't deploy properly.

Answer (score 1):

removing the Spring facet (File->Project Structure)
Kill the project configuration in the facet of the relevant module configuration content, the IDEA is automatically identified. After the removal, the relevant error disappears. Does not affect compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue come when you have created **ObjectService** and instantiated the same in the **RestController** and you havent annotated the **ObjectServiceImpl** with **@Service**.